# HTML of this message exceeds the limit of some mail clients

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email, journeybuilder, email-studio

I have created an email in which there are 2 content blocks. One block fetches the subscriber key(salesforce id) from the email and then creates a table on the email with its associated product name ,quantity and cost. The other content block fetch ID and Email body and updates in a custom field available in salesforce with the body of the email.

When there are few products/relatedItems lets say 5-6 everything works smoothly but when the number of products increases I get a warning
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

> The HTML of this message is approximately 2284.0 KB which exceeds the limit of some mail clients. These clients can show partially rendered messages. (Sometimes 235KB as well)

And for these records the mail is not delivered to the customer(even though in the journey it is successful) and the salesforce field is also not updated. The field remains blank.

This is a major issue we are facing as we are not able to send any emails. Is there any alternative or solution to fix this?

Comment: The fix is to not update a SF object in the email scripting.  Perhaps you can update your question to explain why that's necessary.

Comment: Hi @AdamSpriggs my major concern as of now is how to deliver these emails as we need to display all these products inside the email but due to its HTML size  it is not getting delivered.

Comment: The size is not the problem.